# text color settings in emacs

Tags: emacs, colors, latex

I just switched to emacs from Vim today so I have no idea what I am doing.  How do I change the syntax coloring in Emacs?  Everything is green or light green.

As you can see, latex tex is dark green and regular text is green.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to customize your colors is using the `color-theme` package. The [emacs wiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme) includes instructions on installing and configuring. In Debian, `color-theme` is part of the `emacs-goodies-el` package. Once installed, you can use `M-x color-theme-select` to browse the available themes.

Comment: I have seen that page but don't understand it.  It tells me to put `color-theme.el` in the folder "themes" and other instructions.  First, I have no idea where the folder themes is.  If I have been using emacs for more than 2 hours that site may be helpful, but at the present, it offers nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
M-x load-library RET
M-x color-theme RET
M-x color-theme
```

The above should give you a list to choose from, so you could customize it. Emacs 24+ command

```
M-x load-theme
```

gives you a few more.

Comment: How can I make the change permanent?

Comment: from the options menu, Customize Emacs and then Custom Themes